# Linq query via value conversion defined property

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

Apologies if title is confusing.

I have a User entity, which stores list of external Ids.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int[] ExternalIds { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using [EF Core value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to convert those values to comma separated string.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<int[]>(
        (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
        c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
        c => c.ToArray());

    modelBuilder
        .Entity<User>()
        .Property(user => user.ExternalIds)
        .HasConversion(
            externalIds => string.Join(',', externalIds),
            dbExternalIds => dbExternalIds.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
        .Metadata
        .SetValueComparer(valueComparer);
}
```

Now, I'm having a problem to query via `ExternalIds`.
If I run the following, I get back correctly constructed `User` objects

```
using (var context = new PersonDbContext())
{
    var allUsers = context.Users.ToList();
}
```

However, if I try to query using `ExternalIds` I'm having problems

First try was a simple query like this:

```
var user = 
    context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ExternalIds.Contains(externalId));
```

But this returns no result, which is not surprising as this is generated SQL

```
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[ExternalIds], [u].[Name]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
WHERE CAST(1 AS bit) = CAST(0 AS bit)
```

I was looking into making `Like` queries via EF.Functions but can't make it compile due to `ExternalIds` not being string

```
var user = context.Users
    .FirstOrDefault(u =>
        EF.Functions.Like(u.ExternalIds, "%1%"));
```

What's the correct way to query via property which has value converters ?

While I don't like storing values as comma separated string, putting ExternalIds into dedicated table sounds like an overkill - it's going to have only Ids & nothing else.

I'm using EF Core 3.1 on .Net Core 3.1.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.2" />
```

Comment: I think the only conclusion is that the framework isn't ready for this kind of comparison. You're gonna have to do it yourself client-side, or use a raw SQL query.

Comment: I could finally find a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17879) that covers this specific case. As of this writing it is not supported (EF Core 3.1) and suggestion is to wait for JSON mapping support and try to use that:
`Issue #10434 is tracking support for allowing value converters to influence generation of SQL--I will add a note to consider this case. However, this particular case could end up being too complicated.
This is a case where JSON mapping (#4021) would probably a good fit, once implemented.`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is trick `EntityFramework Core` to think it's a `string` by making it into a first class object and stick an explicit string conversion operator into it.

```cs
public class UserExternalIds : int[]
{
    // Add your validation, initialization, overrides, etc..

    // Only to support ef core query.
    public static explicit operator string(UserExternalIds v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserExternalIds ExternalIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then to write your query you would do it like the following:

Because this is an expression used to translate `linq` into `SQL`, the exception won't be thrown `unless it had to do client side evaluation`.

```cs
// This compiles because of the explicit conversion operator.
var user = 
    context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => ((string)u.ExternalIds).Contains(externalId));
```